# Java program which accepts Integer array as parameter and randomise its values

Tags: java, arrays

I tried a program where I take an integer array and randomise values in it. but I am not able to understand why but am getting a crazy output which displays special characters and all. what's wrong with my question. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Q2d {

    public static void shuffle(int[] arr) {

        int n = arr.length;
        Random random = new Random();
        random.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int change = i + random.nextInt(n - i);
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[change];
            arr[change] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        shuffle(arr);
        System.out.println(arr);

    }
}
```

Comment: That is almost certainly the case, but for future notice you should probably include a sample of the "crazy output"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to print the array object.  Arrays are objects too, but they don't override [`Object`'s `toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), which is responsible for the "crazy output".

Use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you asked this question like 20 minutes ago and in it instead of

```
System.out.println(arr);
```

you had

```
for(int i:arr){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

which is correct...

Comment: I got the answer but was just thinking if there is any better way to do it.

Comment: I think this is probably the most direct way of doing it but rgettman's answer is good too.

Comment: Using a `for` loop means you have to concern yourself with the implementation details of the array, particularly with the type of elements in the array. With `Array.toString()`, you don't ever have to worry about that, which is handy if you have to change array types due to something like design changes.